# Form Activated event and messagebox causes unwanted looping

Tags: vb.net

I am using an activated event in my vb.net application this is followed by an if statement which causes a messagebox to apear as result of a conditon..

The problem is that the messagebox causes my form to loose focus and then re-activate again everytime the messagebox is clicked resulting in a type of loop which I'm now stuck in how can I get round this?

```
      Private Sub form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated

    if "EXTERNAL DOCUMENT IS A DRAWING ENVIRONMENT" then
    'NOTHING
    Else
    msgbox("Select drawing environmet first")
me.close()
    end if

    end sub
```

The line "EXTERNAL DOCUMENT IS A DRAWING ENVIRONMENT" is a procedure where a variable result returned by autodesk inventor identifying what type of drawing environment is the active document... (this just shortens the whole explanation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Tested. But this may work....

```
Private WarningShowed As Boolean = False
Private Sub form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated

    If Not WarningShowed Then
        WarningShowed = True
        If "EXTERNAL DOCUMENT IS A DRAWING ENVIRONMENT" Then
            'NOTHING
        Else
            MsgBox("Select drawing environmet first")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah tops had to play around with it a little bit but seems to do the trick THANKS!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag as Malcor says, or you can remove the handler prior to show the Msg, so:

```
Private Sub form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated

  if "EXTERNAL DOCUMENT IS A DRAWING ENVIRONMENT" then
    'NOTHING
  Else
    RemoveHandler Me.Activated, addressof form1_Activated
    msgbox("Select drawing environment first")
    me.close()
  end if

end sub
```